# How to effectively browse mailing lists

Tags: software, community, software-development

There are many open source projects whose development is officially discussed through mailing lists (the obvious example being [the Linux kernel](http://vger.kernel.org/majordomo-info.html)).

Being young and spoiled by nice clean website design, I find many of these threads unreadable, because it is so difficult to follow. Does anybody know of some kind of mailing list browsing software that I can use to make them a little more readable? Maybe something that can render a mailing list as a messageboard thread? I think that interface is the most analogous to a mailing list.

Comment: Heavy-duty mail readers allow you to sort mail into categories, by threads, by sender/recipient, ... But much of that functionality depends on the sender (minimally) respecting etiquette.

Comment: Mailing list archives are not expected to be a primary interface to the list. Normally, you'd subscribe to the list and read it in your mail client, e.g. Thunderbird. Ideally, that client has a threaded view where replies are nested under the original. Simplified views like Gmail's conversation mode struggle to display a branching topic. Some list servers like Discourse or Google Groups also have a passable web interface, but few lists use them.

Comment: amon can I get archives sent to me? If not, that's not very helpful.

Comment: There are various project management tools with bidirectional binding with SMTP. For example, Redmine.

Comment: Sorry, but sometimes the right answer to "*how do I do X using Y?*" is "*don't use Y to do X*".  This may seem unhelpful, but if there's no good way to use Y to do X, what would you like us to say, other than tell you the right way to accomplish X?  In this case, the usual workflow is to subscribe to the list *then* browse your own archive, as it builds up.

Comment: @MadHatter do you think the concept of a mailing list browser is bad, or does a good implementation of one simply not exist?

Comment: @FredFrey I'm saying that if we pointed you to such a tool right now, you'd have exactly the same problem that you decried above: a nice mailing list browse tool, and no mailing list archive to run it against.

Comment: @MadHatter the archives exist as html on the web. They can be scraped.

Comment: @FredFrey so scrape them and feed them to a good mail client.

Comment: I found this question because I am looking for something similar. The answer appears to be "download the archives and import them into an email client". I'm wondering what solution you landed on? Any tips?

Comment: Basically that. I created a tertiary email account that I won't mind if it gets spammed, and maintain my own archive of the lkml and other mailing lists that way. @chillpenguin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the threaded reading and search facilities of many mailing list web interfaces vary between bad and appalling.  But the principal advantage of mailing lists over web fora, however good the forum, is that **with a mailing list the choice of client is yours**, whereas with a web forum you get whatever software the admin has decided to run, for better or for worse.  I thnk this observation goes far in explaining the [very strong preference for mailing lists](http://www.teaparty.net/pipermail/toasters/2011-August/022948.html) (and consequent dislike of web fora) amongst a certain generation of sysadmins.  The recommended workflow for doing what you want is to subscribe to the list, build your own archive, and then browse it using the mail client of your choice.

Sites like the dear, departed [Gmane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmane) were very useful for keeping archives of important mailing lists open to the major search engines, so that questions with explicit answers (eg, "*What's the best path to upgrade a NetApp filer cluster from 8.3.2P9 to 9.3P17?*") could easily find those answers if they'd already [been posted](http://www.teaparty.net/pipermail/toasters/2020-March/028847.html).  But they weren't, as you point out, great for browsing.

Don't let me stop you searching for the perfect web tool to search your personal archive of any given mailing list, though such a search is [off-topic here](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/688/whats-wrong-with-external-resources-questions).  But I think you'll find that a mail client with good threading capabilities - though I don't use it myself, people speak highly of [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#threads) - is your best bet for doing what you want.

I stipulate that this answer ducks the question of how you get hold of the list archives, but you ducked it in your question by presuming you could get them to run your own web tool on.

Comment: I will accept this, because I don't expect there to be a better answer.